# Address in mailbox given [] does on Laravel

Tags: php, email, pdf, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in there i have been create function for send an email, here my code like this :

```html
$row=DB::table('orders')
->join("cms_members","cms_members.id","=","orders.id_cms_members")
->select("orders.*","cms_members.email as email","cms_members.name as name","cms_members.phone as phone")
->where('orders.id',$id_order)
->first();

$datas = array(
      'name' => 'test',   
      'detail'=> 'test',
      'sender' => 'adamprojo@gmail.com'
  );

$customPaper = array(0,0,800,800);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('testing', $data)->setPaper($customPaper);

Mail::send('emails.temp', $datas, function($message) use($pdf)
{
  $message->from("no-reply@crocodic.net","Invoice HOP Daily rent Orders");
  $message->to($row->email)->subject('Invoice');
  $message->attachData($pdf->output(), "invoice.pdf");
});
```

here my problem when ever i want to send an email i get response

```
Address in mailbox given does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

but if i try to print the email its give me the email address. what should i do ?

Kindly, can someone give me any solution for mentioned problem?

Comment: did you try to type plain email address in `to` method, eg `->to('xyz@gmail.com')`. if not, then try plain email address, see if you receive emails or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be your code:

```
$row=DB::table('orders')
->join("cms_members","cms_members.id","=","orders.id_cms_members")
->select("orders.*","cms_members.email as email","cms_members.name as name","cms_members.phone as phone")
->where('orders.id',$id_order)
->first();

$datas = array(
        'name' => 'test',   
        'detail'=> 'test',
        'sender' => 'adamprojo@gmail.com'
    );

$customPaper = array(0,0,800,800);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('testing', $data)->setPaper($customPaper);

Mail::send('emails.temp', $datas, function($message) use($pdf, $row)
{
  $message->from("no-reply@crocodic.net","Invoice HOP Daily rent Orders");
  $message->to($row->email)->subject('Invoice');
  $message->attachData($pdf->output(), "invoice.pdf");
});
```

You need to set `use($pdf, $row)` by the `Mail::send()`, this will get the `$row` data that you use in the `$message->to()`.

Hope this works!